# The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: php, symfony

I am a beginner with symfony2,  I made my first project, When I switch to production environment to test, I got this error message:

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>   The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
>   Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error >occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

But I executed this command before

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

After, in web app.php I activated

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
I updated my page

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_67a7edb_0" as such route does not exist.").
```

I always execute these commands

```
php php app/console assets:install --symlink
php app/console assetic:dump
php app/console assets:install --symlink --env prod
php app/console assetic:dump --env prod
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

this command `composer.phar show symfony/assetic-bundle` displays

```
name     : symfony/assetic-bundle
descrip. : Integrates Assetic into Symfony2
keywords : assets, compression, minification
versions : * v2.8.1
```

in appKernel

```
public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            {...}
           new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            {...}

        );
```

in config.yml

```
# AsseticBundle Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    bundles:
        # Defaults (all currently registered bundles):
        - BOMyProjectBundle
        - FrameworkBundle
        - SecurityBundle
        - TwigBundle
        - MonologBundle
        - SwiftmailerBundle
        - DoctrineBundle
        - AsseticBundle
    filters:
        lessphp:
            file: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php"
            apply_to: ".less$"
            formatter: "compressed"
            preserve_comments: false
        cssrewrite: ~
    assets:
        jquery_js:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"
            output: "js/jquery.min.js"
        jquery_ui_js:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"
            output: "js/jquery-ui.min.js"
        bootstrap_css:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less"
            filters:
                - lessphp
                - cssrewrite
            output: "css/bootstrap.css"
        bootstrap_js:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/affix.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/alert.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/button.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/carousel.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/collapse.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/modal.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/popover.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/tab.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/transition.js"
            output: js/bootstrap.js
        fonts_glyphicons_eot:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"
        fonts_glyphicons_svg:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"
        fonts_glyphicons_ttf:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"
        fonts_glyphicons_woff:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
        fonts_glyphicons_woff2:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"
        font_awesome_css:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less"
            filters:
                - lessphp
                - cssrewrite
            output: "css/font-awesome.css"
        font_awesome_fonts_eot:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot"
            output: "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot"
        font_awesome_fonts_svg:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg"
            output: "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg"
        font_awesome_fonts_ttf:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"
            output: "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"
        font_awesome_fonts_woff:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff"
            output: "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff"
        font_awesome_fonts_woff2:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2"
            output: "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2"
```

in layout.html.twig

```
{% block stylesheets %}
                        {% stylesheets filter="cssrewrite"
                        '@bootstrap_css'
                        '@fonts_glyphicons_eot'
                        '@fonts_glyphicons_svg'
                        '@fonts_glyphicons_ttf'
                        '@fonts_glyphicons_woff'
                        'css/font-awesome.css'
                        'bundles/bomyproject/css/style.css'
                        output='compiled/css/app.css'
                        %}
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
                        {% endstylesheets %}
                {% endblock %}
<!-- {...} -->
{% block javascript %}
                        {% javascripts filter='?jsqueeze'
                            'bundles/bomyproject/js/*.js' %}
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
                        {% endjavascripts %}
                {% endblock %}
```

I manually remove the cache, and I updated the page, but without success.

Comment: You will often encounter directory permission problems in production or it may be a php version issue.  Edit web/app.php and change $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false); to $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);  With luck this may result in a more useful error page being generated.

Comment: I have already changed the file and I have posted the error message at the top.
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_67a7edb_0" as such route does not exist.").

Comment: Make sure you ran: php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug (Notice the equals sign).  The error message really seems to indicate that it is trying to use development code.  Routes like _assetic_67a7edb_0 really only show up in development.  In any event, use of the bundle is being discouraged.  You might have better luck with an npm based solution such as webpack.

Comment: After the command 

php app / console assetic: dump --env = prod --no-debug

 the production environment is accessible.
Thank you very much, it's been more than 2 weeks with this problem.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Hate to say it but I copied that command directly from the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-prod-environment

Comment: It escaped me to try the options, again thank you Cerad